# creating user with firebaseAuth. but, once registration becomes succesful, other devices devices gets affected as well

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an android app that registers a user to firebase Authentication. So as you can see below this is the program i made to give you a hint on what i am referring . . .

```
public void createAccount(final String email, final String password, final String firstname, final String lastname)
{
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        UserInformation UInfo = new UserInformation(user.getUid(), user.getEmail(), password, firstname, lastname);
                        newRef = database.getReference("Users");
                        newRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue(UInfo);
                        //newRef.child(user.getUid()).child("id").setValue(user.getUid());
                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "User registered: " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

after register succeeds all other devices also gets affected as well, in terms of, all the other devices prompts as if they've just logged in again.

my problem is, why does it do that? why does all other devices gets affected as if they've just logged in again. what's causing the issue?

also, this is my database rules.

```
 {
  "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  }
 }
```

Comment: That is weird! Can you show your firebase auth rule?

Comment: you mean like my database rule? i set it to public. read true, write true? is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, database rule i meant

Comment: i've updated my post. my rules are set to public. i just cant seem to see where is the bug. what's causing my app through affect other devices after it runs to that strip of code